# Transform Binary Operation Function with Different Parameter Types

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stl-algorithm

I am attempting to use `std::transform` to edit a string to output the following:

```
a  
bcd  
efghi  
jklmnop  
qrstuvwxy  
z{abcdefghi  
jklmnopqrstuv  
wxyz{abcdefghij  
klmnopqrstuvwxyz{  
abcdefghijklmnopqrs  
tuvwxyz{abcdefghijklm  
nopqrstuvwxyz{abcdefghi  
jklmnopqrstuvwxyz{abcdefg
```

My transform binary operation function has 2 parameters of different type (`string` and `size_t`). Is it valid/possible to do this? I am also passing the second arg by reference so I can change/increment it, is this valid/possible?

Should I maybe change tact and use a different function from the namespace `algorithm` to achieve this? Maybe `shuffle`, is there a < C++11 function that can achieve this?

```
void solution1()
{
    // Easy solution

    std::string testStr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{";
    size_t index = 1;

    while (index < testStr.length()) {

        std::string back  = testStr.substr(0, index);
        std::string front = testStr.substr(index, std::string::npos);

        testStr = front + back;
        index += 2;
        std::cout << back << std::endl;
    }
}

// anyway to initialise gIndex to 1?
std::string outputOddGroup(std::string str, size_t& gIndex)
{
    // Is there a better way to split and rebuild the string? 
    std::string back  = str.substr(0, gIndex);
    std::string front = str.substr(gIndex, std::string::npos);

    gIndex += 2;
    std::cout << back << std::endl;
    return front + back;
}

void solution2()
{
    std::string testStr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{";
    std::transform(testStr.begin(), testStr.end(), testStr.begin(), outputOddGroup);
}
```

Comment: What does the compiler say? I'd actually be surprised if this even compiles...

Comment: Your solution 2 shouldn't compile. `std::string` doesn't have any constructor that takes a single `char` argument

Comment: I do not think you really understand what `std::transform` does. Please refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your need but how about this solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string testStr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{";
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 13; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << testStr.substr(0, i*2 + 1) << "\n";
        std::rotate(testStr.begin(), testStr.begin() + i*2 + 1, testStr.end());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've used 13 iterations just to mimic your original output so you can change it to whatever number you need.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `std::transform` nor `std::shuffle` (`std::random_shuffle`) addresses your issue. See cppreference for their usage. Anyway, here is my solution, and it runs efficiently.

```
int main() {
    std::string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{";
    for (int cnt = 1, i = 0; cnt < str.size(); cnt += 2) {
        for (int n = cnt; n; --n) {
            std::cout << str[i];
            i = (i + 1) % str.size();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```